# How do I add image overlays to an MKMapView?

Tags: swift, mapkit

----------**UPDATED**------------

original question at the bottom

---

I've gotten pretty far, and I have this now:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var mapView: MKMapView!

    var locationManager: CLLocationManager!
    var mapOverlay: MKOverlay!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var points = [CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -29.8122, longitude: 148.6351),
                      CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -27.9307, longitude: 148.6351),
                      CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -27.9307, longitude: 150.9909),
                      CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -29.8122, longitude: 150.9909)]
        let tile = MKPolygon(coordinates: &points, count: points.count)
        tile.title = "zurich"
        mapView.addOverlay(tile)

        //Setup our Location Manager
        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

        //Setup our Map View
        mapView.delegate = self
        mapView.mapType = MKMapType.satellite
        mapView.showsUserLocation = true
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    // mapView delegate function
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
        let renderer = MKPolygonRenderer(overlay: overlay)
        renderer.fillColor = UIColor.red
        return renderer
    }
}
```

I now need to know how to replace the `renderer.fillColor = UIColor.red` with something that will display my image.
Thanks once again

----- **original question** ------

So, I'm new to Swift and MapKit and I want to add a simple image overlay on top of an MKMapView. I've found a few answers, but they're all confusing, and they are all for Swift 3 and earlier.

I've found that a delegate for the map view is needed, is that a file?
I have already created a map view using the main view controller.

This is what I've done so far (this is in the ViewController.swift file):

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate
{
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    }

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib

        let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 47.457925,
                                              longitude: 8.548466)

        let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.05, longitudeDelta: 0.05)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location, span: span)
        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)


    }


}
```

Thank you and I hope you can help!

Comment: What do you mean by image overlay, could you explain more.. I confused what do you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of way to embed image into your maps.

1. Annotation Views
2. Callouts
3. Custom Map Tile

Explain your need more, and maybe we can help better to how to get there.

---

You are adding overlay over the map. We want to change with specific map tile.

```
func createLocalUrl(forImageNamed name: String) -> URL? {

    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let cacheDirectory = fileManager.urls(for: .cachesDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
    let url = cacheDirectory.appendingPathComponent("\(name).png")

    guard fileManager.fileExists(atPath: url.path) else {
        guard
            let image = UIImage(named: name),
            let data = image.pngData()
            else { return nil }

        fileManager.createFile(atPath: url.path, contents: data, attributes: nil)
        return url
    }

    return url
}

func setupTiles() {
    let url = createLocalUrl(forImageNamed: "yourImageName")
    let template = url?.absoluteString
    let overlay = MKTileOverlay(urlTemplate: template)
    overlay.canReplaceMapContent = true
    self.tileOverlay = overlay
    mapView.addOverlay(overlay)
    self.tileRenderer = MKTileOverlayRenderer(tileOverlay: overlay)
}

func isInDesiredArea(middlePoint: MKMapPoint) -> Bool {

    //mapView has convert function which converts CGPoint -> 
    //CLLocationCoordinate2D and vice versa Use this function and,
    //Your polygon has boundingMapRect which has contains function.
    //Also your map has func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, 
    //regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool) which runs whenever region changes..
    return myBoundsPolygon.boundingMapRect.hasContain(middlePoint)

}


func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {
 //Convert middle point of your view to CLLocationCoordinate2D
 //Convert your coordinate to MKMapPoint
 if isInDesiredArea(middlePoint: point) {
     setupTiles()
 }
}

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
    ....
if overlay is MKTileOverlay {
    return tileRenderer
}
```

Comment: I have an SVG file that I want to overlay on top of the map. I want it to replace or go on top of certain tiles so that it stays in one place when the user pans around or zooms, like what I did here: https://www.flight134.com/airport/lszh/main-level.html using the google maps javascript api

Comment: Sorry for the late response.. You should replace certain map tiles with your image. https://www.raywenderlich.com/823-advanced-mapkit-tutorial-custom-tiles If you didn't see this yet, it would be very helpful. If you did see but you had a trouble with, please explain the problem you have faced.

Comment: thank you for your answer! I used the link and a few other guides to come up with what I have now... I updated the question as it's a bit different now. Essentially I need to replace ```renderer.fillColor = UIColor.red``` with whatever will display the image.

Comment: @flight134 Check this out